# iterate infinite generator until condition is met

Tags: python, generator

I'm having a little trouble understanding generators in python. Lets say I have the following simple generator:

```
def test_gen():
    yield 1
    yield 2
    yield 5
    yield 8
    yield 12
```

That will just yield some numbers. Lets say I want to keep printing values from the generator until the value is more than 10. My first attempt was just

```
gen = test_gen()
for i in gen:
    while i > 10:
        print(i)
```

But this just prints `1` forever. I found that doing

```
gen = test_gen()
for i in gen:
    if i > 10:
        print(i)
```

works as expected because it just iterates through each value in the generator until `StopIteration` is raised. I then ran into the problem of an infinite generator such as this one that generates prime numbers:

```
def prime_gen():
    D = dict()
    n = 2
    while True:
        if n not in D:
            yield n
            D[n*n] = [n]
        else:
            for p in D[n]:
                D.setdefault(p + n, []).append(p)
            del D[n]
        n += 1
```

Then if I do something like

```
primes = prime_gen()
for p in primes:
    if p < 100:
        print(p)
```

then it will print everything up to p, but then get hung up. I think it's getting hung up because it's trying to check every value that `primes` generates, which going on forever. What is the correct way to iterate through an infinite generator until a condition is met like this? The only way I have found is doing

```
primes = prime_gen()
for p in primes:
    if p < 100:
        print(p)
    else:
        break
```

but I feel like there's a more pythonic way of doing it.

Comment: ```while i > 10:
        print(i)``` should it work in different way?

Comment: `if <something>: do_something() else: break` is pretty pythonic and normal.

Comment: Seems like your suggestion is the right answer to me

Answer (score 14):

[`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile)

```
for i in itertools.takewhile(lambda x: x < 100, primes):
  print(i)
```

Comment: It seems it's doing the same thing as in my suggestion in my question. Interestingly, `itertools.takewhile()` is a bit slower than the method in my question when I test it using `%timeit`. Maybe there isn't a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Your `break` method is quite Pythonic, but I would consider wrapping the generator:

```
for p in (i if i < 100 else StopIteration for i in primes):
    print(p)
```

Comment: It gets hung up if you do it this way since it is still trying to check every value generated.

Comment: @greenthumbtack Oops, try again please